# angularjs directive to build widget according to arbitrary js Object with json schema

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to build a widget to render arbitrary data (javascript object) on ui. And the schema of the data is defined by a [json schema](http://json-schema.org) file. And the model must be two-way binding since I want use this widget to input/display data.

Is directive the right way to do this? Is there anyone can give me some clue to achieve this?

Comment: there is already an open source project that handles this sort of thing: http://schemaform.io/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a directive is the right way. You can see that the `angular-schema-form` mentioned in the comments is using directives.

If you'd like to create your own directive. Please have look at the demo below or this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/tchvhfhx/).

The example with the comments is probably not the best because there you wouldn't need the two-way binding of the data.
But it should give you an idea how this could work.

How does the code work?

1. It loops over `schema.items.properties` and creates a template with `ng-model` / `ng-restrict` and all bindings added to the template.
2. After the loop is done the `$compile` service is adding the current scope to the template.
3. Replace the html with the compiled template.

The demo is probably pretty basic compared to the `angular-schema-form` code but it's easier to understand and easier to modifiy to your needs.

```js
angular.module('demoApp', [])
    .controller('mainController', MainController)
    .directive('awDisplayJsonView', DisplayJsonView)
    .directive('awDateParser', DateParser);

/**
 * Translates unix time stamp into readable dates 
 * from model/view & view/model
*/
function DateParser() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelController) {
      ngModelController.$parsers.push(function(data) {
        //convert data from view format to model format
        return new Date(data).getTime(); //converted
      });

      ngModelController.$formatters.push(function(data) {
        //convert data from model format to view format
        return new Date(parseInt(data)).toUTCString(); //converted return UTC
      });
    }
  }
}

function MainController() {
    angular.extend(this, {
        /*jsonView: {
            "text": { // name of model
                type: "input",
                label: "Two way binded input",
            }
        },*/
        jsonModel: [{
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Test User",
            "text": "I am a comment.",
            "date": "1435427542904",
        }, {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Antother User",
            "text": "I am the second comment.",
            "date": "1435427605064",
        }],

        jsonSchema: {
            "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
            "title": "Comments",
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
                "title": "Comment",
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "id": {
                        "description": "The unique identifier for a comment.",
                        "type": "number",
                        "format": "hidden" // not sure if this is the right place
                    },
                    "name": {
                        "title": "Name",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "text": {
                        "title": "Comment",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "date": {
                        "title": "Date (format y/m/d hh:mm:ss GMT)",
                        "type": "string",
                        "format": "date-time"
                    }
                },
                "required": [
                    "id",
                    "name",
                    "text"]
            }
        }
    });
}

function DisplayJsonView($compile) {
    var templatesObj = {
        string: function (hidden) {
            return $('<input/>')
                .attr('type', hidden)
                .addClass('form-control');
        },
        checkbox: function (hidden) {
            return $('<input/>')
                .attr('type', hidden || 'checkbox')
                .addClass('form-control');
        },
        number: function(hidden) {
            return $('<input/>')
                .attr('type', hidden)
                .addClass('form-control');
        }
    };
    
    function render(schema, model, index) {
        var outTemplate = $(document.createDocumentFragment()),
            tempTmpl, hidden; // temporary template, hidden input
        
        angular.forEach(schema.items.properties, function (prop, key) {
            //console.log(key, prop.type, prop.format, templatesObj[prop.type]);
            hidden = prop.format == 'hidden'? 'hidden': null;
            tempTmpl = templatesObj[prop.type](hidden); // get template based on type
            tempTmpl.attr({
                'ng-model': 
                    'model[' + index + '].' + key, // add current model
                'ng-required': schema.items.required.indexOf(key) != -1 // check if it is required
            });
            
            if (prop.format == 'date-time')
                tempTmpl.attr('aw-date-parser', ''); // add directive if we have a date
                
            outTemplate.append($('<div/>').addClass('form-group')
                .append(!hidden ? $('<label/>').text(prop.title || key) : null) //add label if not hidden
                .append(tempTmpl));
        });
        //console.log(model, outTemplate);
        return outTemplate;
    }
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {
            //view: '=', // angular schema form does implement this
            model: '=',
            schema: '='
        },
        template: '<div>{{schema |json:2}}</div>',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var out = $('<form/>');
            
            angular.forEach(scope.model, function(item, index) {
                //console.log(item);
                out.append(render(scope.schema, item, index));
            });
            var compiled = $compile(out)(scope);
            //console.log(scope.model, scope.schema);
            element.replaceWith(compiled);
        }
    };
}

DisplayJsonView.$inject = ['$compile'];
```

```css
body {
    padding: 0.5em;
}
.form-group {
    padding-bottom: 0.25em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.1/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="mainController as ctrl">
    <h3>Comments list with schema json directive</h3>
    <form  name="form" aw-display-json-view="" data-model="ctrl.jsonModel" data-schema="ctrl.jsonSchema" ng-cloak=""></form>
    <div ng-cloak>
    {{form|json}}
    {{ctrl.jsonModel}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Awolf! Seems angular-schema-form can save me a lot of work. I'll take some time to study it.